# I need to edit price on paypal page

Tags: magento2

I need to edit price that is displayed on paypal page on top right. I have set a condition that if the order total is > 25 then free shipping is set else 10$ flat rate. When I land on paypal login page on top right near cart symbol it displayed + 10 cost.

For ex in attach screenshot I made a order of 26 & on top right on paypal page it is displaying 36. Can any one guide me from where can I edit this?

[image]

Comment: how about actually applying free shipping?

Comment: I had set free shipping but the only issue is i am not getting from where is the amount value passed